# How to debug appearance of keyboard?

Tags: ios

I have a view that momentarily shows the keyboard when it first loads, for no obvious reason. How can I debug what's causing the keyboard to appear? Is there symbolic breakpoint for showing the keyboard?

Comment: Usually the keyboard is shown when a text field or a text view becomes first responder.

Comment: @dasdom True that. This particular view has neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a symbolic breakpoint for `UIResponder` method, [becomeFirstResponder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621113-becomefirstresponder). I guess UIResponder is still in Objective-C so use Objective-C syntax for symbolic breakpoint.

[image]

In case you are not able to figure out first responder using this breakpoint, as it may not give you that info, you can try to force end editing in viewWillAppear method of your ViewController:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```